# How to set google.visualization.ColorFormat where addRange containing string

Tags: google-visualization

I want to add ColorFormat to the code of drawing table in google visualize API.

I have five values in the selected column:Very Healthy, Healthy, Caution, Not Healthy, Remark

when this value in the row is "Not Healthy", the color should change

```
 var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
    formatter.addRange(from, to, 'white', '#ff0000');
    formatter.format(tdata, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
```

How should I set the String boundaries of formatter.addRange() in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't solved this or someone else stumbles upon this question - The colour formatter for strings is case sensitive and only requires the first letter of the string to select the range. In your case this *should* mean that you can set your from parameter to 'M' and your to parameter to 'O' which will select string entries beginning with 'N'.

```
formatter.addRange('M', 'O', 'white', '#ff0000');
```